# SVN - Ignore Symlinks

Tags: svn, version-control

Is it possible to have SVN ignore all symlinks?

The particular situation I am trying to achieve is this:

Web framework under source control on its own

Additions to the framework are each modularised and kept separate to the framework and symlinked in as and when required.

These separate modules are also each under svn.

Answer (score 1):

Subversion doesn't recognize symlinks as links to other files or directories, but as the actual files and directories they link to.  You can witness this working in VIM, say you have file a.ext and you ln -s a.ext - b.ext then you vi/vim b.ext, if will open for editing as if it were a file in it's own right and not a link.

You will unfortunately need to manually ignore any symlinks that you don't want to commit.

Comment: ⁺¹, so long was seeking just to find: whether SVN works with symlinks separately, or it thinks it is the dir/file to which it is linked. Thank you.